# Why do rules I create in graphic firewall (gufw) get deleted (force deleted)?

Tags: firewall, ufw, gufw

I used the graphic firewall in 18.04 to create rules for 3 services. At the time they were created, the rules were fine and the items accessible from other machines on my home network.

The next day, nothing worked. When I check the firewall log, I see entries like this:

```
 06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 1 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 1 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 2 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 2 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 3 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 3 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 4 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 4 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 5 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 5 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 6 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 6 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 7 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 7 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 8 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 8 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 9 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 9 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 10 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 10 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 11 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 11 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 12 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 12 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 13 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 13 > Rule deleted | 
[06/15/2018 07:00:39 AM] Deleting previous rules: 14 /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 14 > Rule deleted |
```

I did not delete these rules. I checked preferences and I searched online and could not find a similar issue.

What could be the cause of the rules I create one day being deleted the next day?

Comment: Update: I may close this question. It appears I just need to learn more about gufw. I just activated all the profiles, home, office and public and my rules came back. So currently no problem and all my affected apps are accessible once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are still in place after 3 days and have not been deleted. I believe I did this inadvertently while trying to setup the rules I needed.